# How can I write a loop in vba for this code

Tags: excel, vba, loops, charts

```
59.30   15                16                   17
1    1,162,912,036.90    1,248,737,016.99    1,306,573,912.08 
2    245,665,383.94      261,416,880.69      276,613,283.05 
3    393,313,441.29      379,169,039.15      418,680,492.19 
4    13,920,572.74       14,464,854.92       15,120,474.58 
5    54,501,581.55       56,319,351.21       58,832,588.24 
6    15,165,376.28       11,694,942.56       10,809,661.03 
7    194,397,643.30      170,427,013.85      182,567,862.46 
8    15,165,376.28       11,694,942.56       10,809,661.03 
9    2,079,876,036.00    2,142,229,099.38    2,269,198,273.62
     3%                  6%
```

There are 7 tables like the above data in one excel tab in different area.I want to create a stacked column chart for each table. I wrote a code to create. Just want to know is that possiable to use loop to solve this problem? Code attached.

Sub FormatChartNIX()
    'PURPOSE: Create a chart (chart dimensions are not required)

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim cht As Object
Dim ser As Series
Dim tmpCHR As ChartObject

'Chart1
        'Your data range for the chart
          Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B8:E17")

        'Create a chart
          Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart

        'Give chart some data
          cht.chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng, PlotBy:=xlRows

        'Determine the chart type
          cht.chart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        With ActiveSheet
         .ChartObjects(1).Top = .Range("C24").Top
         .ChartObjects(1).Left = .Range("C24").Left
         End With
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
Selection.delete
ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("c1")

'Chart2
           Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("G8:J17")
          Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
          cht.chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng, PlotBy:=xlRows
          cht.chart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        With ActiveSheet
         .ChartObjects(2).Top = .Range("H24").Top
         .ChartObjects(2).Left = .Range("H24").Left
         End With
         ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(2).Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
Selection.delete
ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("h1")
'Chart3
           Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("L8:o17")
          Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
          cht.chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng, PlotBy:=xlRows
          cht.chart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        With ActiveSheet
         .ChartObjects(3).Top = .Range("M24").Top
         .ChartObjects(3).Left = .Range("M24").Left
         End With
         ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(3).Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
Selection.delete
ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("h1")
'Chart4
           Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B82:E91")
          Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
          cht.chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng, PlotBy:=xlRows
          cht.chart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        With ActiveSheet
         .ChartObjects(4).Top = .Range("C51").Top
         .ChartObjects(4).Left = .Range("C51").Left
         End With
                   ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(4).Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
Selection.delete
ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("c75")
 'Chart5
           Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("G82:J91")
          Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
          cht.chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng, PlotBy:=xlRows
          cht.chart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        With ActiveSheet
         .ChartObjects(5).Top = .Range("H51").Top
         .ChartObjects(5).Left = .Range("H51").Left
         End With
                   ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(5).Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
Selection.delete
 ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("h75")

'Chart6
           Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("L82:o91")
          Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
          cht.chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng, PlotBy:=xlRows
          cht.chart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        With ActiveSheet
         .ChartObjects(6).Top = .Range("M51").Top
         .ChartObjects(6).Left = .Range("M51").Left
         End With
                   ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(6).Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
Selection.delete
 ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("m75")
 'Chart7
           Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("Q82:T91")
          Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
          cht.chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng, PlotBy:=xlRows
          cht.chart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        With ActiveSheet
         .ChartObjects(7).Top = .Range("R51").Top
         .ChartObjects(7).Left = .Range("R51").Left
         End With
                   ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(7).Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
Selection.delete
 ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("r75")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using named ranges and some arrays you can loop through it.
First, create named ranges for the ranges for each chart.

I added a small table in the spreadsheet and named each one the text in the first cell of the range (i.e., Chart1,... Chart7).  The other ranges each go in the next cell, so the range named "Chart 1" is 4 cells.

(I also used the same ranges and cells that you did in your code above)

Chart1  B8:E17  C24 C1 
Chart2  G8:J17  H24 H1 
Chart3  L8:O17  M24 H1 
Chart4  B82:E91 C51 C75 
Chart5  G82:J91 H51 H75 
Chart6  L82:O91 M51 R75 
Chart7  Q82:T91 R51 R75

```
Sub FormatChartNIX_Modified()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cht As Object
Dim ser As Series
Dim tmpCHR As ChartObject
Dim MyArray(1 To 7, 0 To 3) As String
Dim i As Integer


For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
        'Set Values - possibly with named ranges
        Dim vArray() As Variant
        Dim strNamedRange As String

        strNamedRange = "Chart" & i

        Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(strNamedRange)
        vArray = rng

        Dim j As Integer

        For j = LBound(MyArray, 2) To UBound(MyArray, 2)

            MyArray(i, j) = vArray(1, j + 1)
            Debug.Print MyArray(i, j)

        Next j

    Next i

    For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)

            With ActiveSheet
                Set rng = .Range(MyArray(i, 1))                     '1 represents the data range
                Set cht = .Shapes.AddChart
                cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng, PlotBy:=xlRows
                cht.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked

                .ChartObjects(i).Top = .Range(MyArray(i, 2)).Top    '0 represents the chart name
                .ChartObjects(i).Left = .Range(MyArray(i, 2)).Left  '2 represents the cell identifying the chart location
                .ChartObjects(i).Activate
                With ActiveChart
                .Axes(xlValue).Select
                .Axes(xlValue).Delete
                .HasTitle = True
                .ChartTitle.Text = ActiveSheet.Range(MyArray(i, 3)).Text '3 represents the cell where the title text is located
                End With
            End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Do that, run the sub and it will create 7 charts as described in the table - using a loop.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to run it but I got run time error 1004, application-defined or object-defined error on   Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(MyArray(i, 1))

Comment: I'm also having issues now.  I didn't when I answered - Let me look at it.

Comment: Ok - I edited the code above.  The only time I get errors now is if I don't delete all of the charts before running the sub again (because of how code-created charts are named we end up with duplicate named charts).

I also added your sample data in the fields for the first graph (B8:E17) just to test it and all worked out.